# How to check element exists in SplPriorityQueue?

Tags: php, priority-queue, spl

I've custom SplPriorityQueue.

```
class Application_Model_Astar_PQtest extends SplPriorityQueue 
{ 
    public function compare($priority1, $priority2) 
    { 
        if ($priority1 === $priority2) return 0; 
        return $priority1 > $priority2 ? -1 : 1; 
    } 
}
```

How to check whether element exists in this queue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SplPriorityQueue` implements an iterator, so just iterate over it:

```
$foundIt = false;

foreach($queue as $item){

  if($item !== 'element')
    continue;

  $foundIt = true;
  break;
}
```

---

Alternatively:

```
$foundIt = in_array('element', iterator_to_array($queue));
```

Comment: You probably want to `clone $queue` when searching, else all of the items will get `extract()`-ed.